# SFINAE for detecting if size method is implemented doesn't work with vector of vector

Tags: c++, sfinae

I expect this code will work with vector of vector but it seems to detect the existence of size only for the external vector. Anyone can help?

```
    #include <iostream>
#include <vector>
 

// SFINAE test
template <typename T>
class has_size
{
    typedef char one;
    struct two { char x[2]; };

    template <typename C> static one test( decltype(&C::size) ) ;
    template <typename C> static two test(...);    

public:
    enum { value = sizeof(test<T>(0)) == sizeof(char) };
};


 
    
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  
    float x=2;
    std::cout << typeid(x).name() << '\n';
    std::cout << has_size<decltype(x)>::value << std::endl;
    std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<float>>> y{};
    std::cout << typeid(y).name() << '\n';
    std::cout << has_size<decltype(y)>::value << std::endl;
    std::cout << typeid(y.at(0)).name() << '\n';
    std::cout << has_size<decltype(y.at(0))>::value << std::endl;
    std::cout << typeid(y.at(0).at(0)).name() << '\n';
    std::cout << has_size<decltype(y.at(0).at(0))>::value << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Below you can find the output:

```
f 0

St6vectorIS_IS_IfSaIfEESaIS1_EESaIS3_EE 1 

St6vectorIS_IfSaIfEESaIS1_EE 0 

St6vectorIfSaIfEE 0
```

Comment: BTW, with C++20 concepts, traits would be simpler: `requires(T t) { t.size();}`.

Answer (score 0):

Your tests are wrong:

`decltype(y.at(0))` is actually `std::vector<std::vector<float>>&` (note the reference).

you need `std::decay`/`std::remove_reference` for your tests, i.e.:

`has_size<std::decay_t<decltype(y)>>::value`